# error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘{’ token

Tags: c

I'm trying to compile with gcc a code which create a list of random integers, and sort it. But i'm getting these errors :

```
main.c:8:1: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘{’ token
    8 | {
      | ^
tri.c:8:1: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘{’ token
    8 | {
      | ^
```

My first file main.c contains :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tri.h"
#include "annexe.h"


int main(void)
{
    int *T;
    int n,d,k;
    char e;
    do
    {
        Saisir_n1(n);
        trait();
        T=CreaTablD(n);
        AffichageD(T,n);
        do
        {
            printf("\nChoisir entre le tri par insertion (1) et le tri par selection (2) : ");
            scanf("%d",&d);
        }while(d!=1 && d!=2);
        do
        {
            printf("\nChoisir entre un tri par ordre décroissant (d) et un tri par ordre croissant (c) : ");
            scanf("%c", &e);
        }while(e!='c' && e!='d');
        trait();
        if (d==1)
            Tri_Insertion(T,n,e);
        else
            Tri_Selection(T,n,e);
        AffichageD(T,n);
        free(T);
        do
        {
            printf("\nVoulez-vous recommencer ?\nOui(1)\tNon(0) : ");
            scanf("%d"&k);
        }while(k!=1 && k!=0);
    }while(k==1);
    return(0);
}
```

And my second file tri.c contains :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "annexe.h"



void Tri_Insertion(int *T, int n, char choix)
{
    int cle,j;
    if (choix!='c' && choix!='d')
    {
        printf("\nErreur dans le choix des paramètres\n");
        return;
    }
    for (int i=1; i<n;i++)
    {
        cle=*(T+i);
        j=i-1
        if (choix=='c')
        {
            while (j>0 && *(T+j)>cle)
            {
                *(T+j+1)=*(T+i);
                j--;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            while (j>0 && *(T+j)<cle)
                {
                    *(T+j+1)=*(T+i);
                    j--;
                }
        }
        *(T+j+1)=cle;
    }
}

void Tri_Selection(int *T, int n, char choix)
{
    int ie,e;
    if (choix!='c' && choix!='d')
    {
        printf("\nErreur dans le choix des paramètres\n");
        return;
    }
    if (choix=='c')
    {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            PlusPetitD(T,ie,e,0,n);
            if (ie!=i)
            {
                permutationD(T+i,T+ie);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            PlusGrandD(T,ie,e,0,n);
            if (ie!=i)
            {
                permutationD(T+i,T+ie);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

annexe.c is a file where I'm pretty sure there is no problem because it works with another files.
I checked all the "}" and "{", all the ";" and no one is missing.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What about the header files? Are they OK?

Comment: You should re-check your "annexe.h" file, most likely the issue is there

Comment: `scanf("%d"&k);` missing a comma there

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yeah I think so, I added all my function in with ";" on the end of each function declaration

Comment: @UnholySheep I re-checked, I can't see any problem in there

Comment: @GovindParmar yes ! thanks, but the problem remain.

Comment: Generally when you're getting an error like this its as a result of not closing a parentheses, block quote, etc. properly. In this case, I believe it's your scanf("%d"&k); line missing a comma

Comment: You're also missing a semicolon in your tri.c, triInsertion(): `j=i-1`

Comment: As a first step, you can simply comment out the include directives and see whether the error disappears. You'll of course get a  lot of undeclared identifiers errors but the brace error should be gone.

Comment: Second step is to comment out parts of the header files in a kind of binary search and see when the error (dis)appears. You could also simply paste the header into the c file, or perhaps write a minimal c file for this test purpose, and paste the header in there.

Comment: Please update your question with the contents of annexe.h.  The error is most likely there.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I found the error doing your steps ! Thank you ! The error was a missing ")" in "annexe.h". I also added some "&" where functions are using int* and not int.

Comment: Glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

Almost certain it's in your Tri_Insertion() function - you have the following unterminated line which is probably throwing a compiler error (it seems to be about line 8 of your tri.c file:

```
    j=i-1
    if (choix=='c')
    {
```

which should instead be:

```
    j=i-1;
    if (choix=='c')
    {
```

Comment: yes thx, it was indeed a semi colon I forgot, but the problem was a missing "(" in "annexe.h"

Answer (score 0):

Your second file is called tri.c , but in main you include it as a header file `#include "tri.h"` . Is that correct?

Comment: I have a file named "tri.h" which contains :
`void Tri_Insertion(int *T, int n, char choix);
void Tri_Selection(int *T, int n, char choix);`
And I think it is correct, I actually already worked like that on other code without problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).